# Aligning expandable divs in row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align these blocks so they are expandable, but also inline. But I can't seem to get them to maintain their own space correctly. The layout I am going for is as follows

[image]

Where box 2, and 3 are auto expanding to fill in space on whatever resolution is viewing.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/nf3d96hq/)** and **[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/ohhb5axm/)**

CSS / HTML:

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 1005px;
  max-width: 1428px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
.box1 {
  float: left;
  width: 455px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.box2 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 340px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 50, 50, 0.75);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.box3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 190px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 100, 0.75);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.box4 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 100, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Test</div>
  <div class="box2">Test</div>
  <div class="box3">Test</div>
  <div class="box4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you are trying to get 4 flexible boxes in line that will always take up 100% of the container correct?

Comment: Yeah, except box4 will be on a new line taking up 100%.

Comment: This as close as I have gotten on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/ohhb5axm/) Which they don't really auto expand

Comment: I suppose it could, though I was trying to stray away from using tables for any template elements and just aligning text.

Comment: display:table; display:table-row; display:table-cell; to the rescue.

Comment: So it'd be something like `tablecontainer > rowcontainer > top 3 celldivs > rowcontainer > footer celldiv` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here are three techniques

"Show code snippet" and run to see the complete example.

### #1 -  `display: inline-block` and calc

**Compatibility**: [IE 9 + and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). There are workarounds to get this working with IE8+ if needed.

- The margins and fixed column are removed from the percentage calculation with `width: calc(50% - 60px)`
- The divs are given `min-height: 100%` and will re-size with content. This is possible thanks to
  `html,body { height: 100%; }`
- The inline gap is removed by placing the closing div tags right next to the next opening tag. [More info here.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

#### Example

Note:  The child selectors can be replaced with class selectors if wanted.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #f50057;
  min-height: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: calc(50% - 60px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
/*Fix first div*/

div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}
/*Remove third divs right margin*/

div:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}
/*Top margin for last div*/

div:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

### #2 - `display: table` / `display: table-cell`

**Compatibility**: [IE 8 + and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

- The top three divs are wrapped in a div with `display: table`
- The top three divs are given `display: table-cell`
- The fixed left div is given a fixed width
- To allow the "cells" to evenly spread out the available width, the wrapper is given `table-layout: fixed`
- The spacing between the top three divs is given by the border property. This is calculated into the percentage calculation thanks to `* { box-sizing: border-box }`
- The bottom div is outside the wrapper and is given `display: block`. It is given a top border to create the faux margin

#### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table > div {
  background: #f50057;
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: solid 10px #FFF;
}
.table > div:first-child {
  border-left: none;
  width: 100px;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #f50057;
  height: 50%;
  border-top: solid 10px #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

### #3 - The future! `display: flex`

**Compatibility**: [IE 11, all modern browsers and Safari (with `-webkit-` prefix)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

This is my **favourite!** Mainly due to the fact that I created it in about 3 minutes.

- The top three divs are wrapped in a container with `display: flex`
- The first div is given its fixed pixel width and `flex: 0 0 auto`. This tells the div not to grow or shrink
- The 2 flexible divs are given `flex: 1` and will grow and shrink as needed; automatically ignoring the fixed column
- The last div is outside the flex container and is independent
- The height and widths of the flexible divs are created with [viewport width (`vw`) and viewport height (`vh`) units.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

[Refer here for a fantastic flexbox guide.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

#### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.flex > div {
  background: #f50057;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.flex > div:first-child {
  width: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #f50057;
  height: calc(50vh - 10px);
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: 3 great solutions!!! But note that the only one that does not require making an extra div in the html is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Its not perfect but seems to do what you want with css tables.

```
<div class="table">

  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tcell">box1</div>
    <div class="tcell">box2</div>
    <div class="tcell">box3</div>
  </div>

</div>   

<div class="table">
    <div class="tcell last">box4</div>
</div> 

.table{display:table; width:100%; text-align:center;}
.tcell{display:table-cell; background:#000; color:#fff; min-height:100px; padding:20px; border:1px solid #fff; }
.trow{display:table-row;  }
.last{ background:red; }
.trow .tcell:first-child{ width:300px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fjsvnrLp/5/

You dont actually need the row

Comment: The entire point of the question was to find out how to keep the first box a fixed width and make the other 2 have a width based depending on room left right of box1 . Your solution ignores the fixed width of box1.